# CORS error when proxying websockets in spring boot with nginx

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, websocket

trying to proxy websocket connections in spring boot application with nginx with config (without nginx it works ok)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

however getting following error js:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/gs-guide-websocket/776/ybicrrun/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

spring:

```
o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Reject: 'http://localhost' origin is not allowed
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 403 FORBIDDEN, headers={masked}
```

what is the correct way to proxy web socket connections?

Comment: "Reject: 'http://localhost' origin is not allowed" - perhaps check who and why is this produced?

Comment: @Smutje well, I can see this is happening because in spring request origin is localhost (not localhost:8080), not sure how to fix this in nginx correct way

Comment: My point is: If you need help on how to configure Spring, you should ask people working for Spring

Answer (score 0):

found one way to [configure allowed origin in spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-allowed-origins):

```
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new MyHandler();
    }

}
```

still think this is not a proper way, looking how to fix it on nginx

Comment: The `Origin` header is set by the browser - so either rewrite the header or allow the original header the browser sends.